# VS Code Flask debug running much slower compared to running Flask from command line (with same parameters)

Tags: python, debugging, flask, visual-studio-code

I am currently in early developing stages of a flask app in VS Code and I don't understand why I have huge runtime differences between starting the flask app using the VS Code debugger and when I start my flask app from the command line(5 to 6 times slower in VS code debugging), but with the same flask parameters. This seems to mainly happen when I use pandas/numpy objects.

I have the following content in my launch.json (only content relevant to "Python: Flask"

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "test_flask_app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload",
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
```

I then click on "Start debugging" and the following is displayed in the terminal:

```
 * Serving Flask app "test_flask_app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I start Flask from the command line with the following commands:
    export FLASK_APP=test_flask_app.py
    export FLASK_ENV=devlopment
    flask run --no-debugger --no-reload

The following information is displayed on startup (identical to the first one):

```
 * Serving Flask app "test_flask_app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The strange thing is that the runtime time of one page takes about 800ms when I run Flask directly from the terminal and 5 to 6 seconds when I run Flask from VS Code debugger.

I believe all my parameters are identical (and I can of course start my Flask manually), but I would like to understand why there is such a big difference in runtimes ?

Here is the sample code I used:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask

# vectorized function
def generateHeaderObject(text, level, calc, axis):
    return "." * int(level) + text + '|' + str(False) + '|' + "" + '|' + \
        "hdr " + axis + "ht" + (" " + axis + "agg" if calc else "")

# create sample dataframe
n = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    calc=np.random.choice(a=[False,True],size=n),
    level=np.random.randint(1, 12, size=n),
    id=np.random.randint(10000000, 99999999, size=n)
))
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/') 
# ‘/’ URL is bound with hello_world() function. 
def main():
    # Calculate new column
    start = time.time()
    df['output'] = np.vectorize(generateHeaderObject)(
        df['id'], df['level'], df['calc'], "r"
    )
    return 'runtime np.vectorize (ms): ' + str((time.time() - start) * 1000)
```

Comment: What is your `launch.json` configuration? And what do you mean by "debugging is not on" when you said you are "starting flask from VSCode (by running a python file **in debug mode**)"?

Comment: I edited the original question to make it more specific (based on my latest findings) and added the launch.json information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply overhead from using the debugger due to it having to run within your Flask application. If you use "Run without Debugging" in VS Code you won't see the slowdown.

Comment: I tried that too by settings the following in the "launch.json"  
`"env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "test_flask_app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "production",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "0",
`
and my settings are applied
`* Serving Flask app "test_flask_app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
but I get the same slow runtime (5+ seconds)

Comment: It's not controlled via your `launch.json`, it's _how_ you launch your program. Use `Run` -> `Run Without Debugging` (Ctrl-F5) and that will use your `launch.json` to run your code but not actually hook up the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, I did not realize that the problem was how I was running it and not my launch.json configuration